# ErrorException - Array to String Conversion [Laravel]

Tags: arrays, string, laravel, request

For some reason I'm getting the Array to String Conversion when processing a Request through the controller.

My script creates multiple entries in the database, and I can't seem to figure out where my errors are.

```
public function storeMappool(MappoolFormRequest $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'tournament_id',
        'game_id',
        'name',
        'content',
    ]);

    $inputForm = $request->all();

    if (!TournamentMappool::where('name', $inputForm['name'])->where('tournament_id', $inputForm['tournament_id'])->exists())
    {
        print("Creating new TournamentMappool entry.<br>");
        $inputM = array();
        $inputM['tournament_id'] = $inputForm['tournament_id'];
        $inputM['name'] = $inputForm['name'];
        $mappool = TournamentMappool::create($inputM);
    }
    else
    {
        return "Mappool Name already exists.";
    }


    $maps_arr = explode("\r\n", $inputForm['content']);
    foreach ($maps_arr as $map) {
        $map_arr = explode("||", $map);
        $map_bmid = str_replace("https://osu.ppy.sh/b/", "", $map_arr[0]);

        $bmi = json_decode ( file_get_contents ( 'http://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_beatmaps?k=<api_key>&b='.$map_bmid), true )[0];

        if (!GameMap::where('external_id', $bmi['beatmapset_id'])->exists())
        {
            print("Creating new GameMap entry.<br>");
            $input = array();
            $input['game_id'] = $request->input('game_id');
            $input['external_id'] = $bmi['beatmapset_id'];
            $input['mapname'] = $bmi['artist'] . " - " . $bmi['title'];
            $gameMap = GameMap::create($input);

            $bmsi = json_decode ( file_get_contents ( 'http://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_beatmaps?k=<api_key>&s='.$bmi['beatmapset_id']), true );
            foreach ($bmsi as $mapset) {
                print("Creating new GameMapVersion entry.<br>");
                $inputV = array();
                $inputV['map_id'] = $gameMap->id;
                $inputV['version'] = $mapset['version'];
                $inputV['external_id'] = $mapset['beatmap_id'];
                $inputV['external_data'] = $mapset;
                $gameMapVersion = GameMapVersion::create($inputV);

                if ($gameMapVersion->external_id == $bmi['beatmap_id'])
                {
                    $inputMm = array();
                    $inputMm['mappool_id'] = $mappool->id;
                    $inputMm['version_id'] = $gameMapVersion->id;
                    $inputMm['modifier'] = $map_arr[1];
                    TournamentMappoolMap::create($inputMm);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $gameMap = GameMap::where('external_id', $bmi['beatmapset_id'])
                              ->where('game_id', $inputForm['game_id'])
                              ->first();
            $gameMapVersion = GameMapVersion::where('map_id', $gameMap->id)
                                            ->where('external_id', $bmi['beatmap_id'])
                                            ->first();
            $inputMm = array();
            $inputMm['mappool_id'] = $mappool->id;
            $inputMm['version_id'] = $gameMapVersion->id;
            $inputMm['modifier'] = $map_arr[1];
            TournamentMappoolMap::create($inputMm);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope someone is able to help me figure out where my errors are and how to fix this issue.

The results returned from the API are as follow:

```
[{"beatmapset_id":"210346","beatmap_id":"495633","approved":"1","total_length":"244","hit_length":"232","version":"captin's Legend","file_md5":"afc04f1f8dcd0dfac51bae4459f052e1","diff_size":"4.3","diff_overall":"9","diff_approach":"9.3","diff_drain":"7","mode":"0","approved_date":"2015-07-03 00:20:14","last_update":"2015-06-26 00:01:19","artist":"Nanahoshi Kangengakudan","title":"IMAGINARY LIKE THE JUSTICE","creator":"pkk","bpm":"190","source":"","tags":"pkmnyab kibbleru frostings captin1 vocaloid megpoid gumi vocarock orchestra illicit sexual relations monaka \u30e2\u30ca\u30ab exit tunes presents storytellers rpg fujuniseikouyuup \u4e0d\u7d14\u7570\u6027\u4ea4\u904ap iwami takashi \u5ca9\u898b\u9678","genre_id":"7","language_id":"3","favourite_count":"887","playcount":"570073","passcount":"26473","max_combo":"1697","difficultyrating":"6.111269474029541"}]
```

Hopefully there is enough information to help me figure out the error.

If any other classes like models are needed feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the error... I've overlooked the JSON_decode parts as I decode it to use it inside the $input generation.

I've fixed it by using: `$inputV['external_data'] = json_encode($mapset);`